# How to convert CSV data into LabelledPoint format?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

In the example provided here http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-clustering.html#streaming-k-means the data is already in LabelledPoint format but I have a csv file with separate label and feature columns (and theyre both text).

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a direct way to transform a CSV into a LabeledPoint.

This is the code that I usually use:

```
val csv = sc.textFile("PATH/TO/CSVFILE")

val lPoint = csv.map { line =>
  val values = line.split(",").map(_.toDouble)
  val features = Vectors.dense(values.init)
  //Assuming that the label is always in the last column.
  val label = values.last
  LabeledPoint(label, features)
}
```

Comment: This is in Scala while the original question is asking for Python Implementation